# How to play video from server url in video view android

Tags: android, android-videoview

How can i play video from live URL using video view. i implemented some code which works perfect when i play with local URL (from xampp server). but when i change same to URL to live URL it stop playing. and shows cant't play this video.
it does not throw any error. 
any help appreciate.
here below i put some code which i implement for play video from local URL.

```
try {

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoViewPlayer);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoViewPlayer);
        videoViewPlayer.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoViewPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoPath));
        videoViewPlayer.requestFocus();
        videoViewPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new 
        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                videoViewPlayer.start();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are you playing Youtube url ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it will work for you,

```
try {
        String link="http://s1133.photobucket.com/albums/m590/Anniebabycupcakez/?action=view&amp; current=1376992942447_242.mp4";
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: @rkandroid Do u have the permissions added for internet access?